# ubiquity automatic install stops at keyboard layout chooser

Tags: automation, ubiquity

I am trying to automate 12.04.1 64bit installation using **ubiquity** & **preseed** on a desktop live CD.

It almost works fine. I edited the `txt.cfg` and added

```
label unattended
  menu label ^Unattended installation
  kernel /casper/vmlinuz
  append  file=/cdrom/preseed/custom.seed boot=casper initrd=/casper/initrd.lz quiet  splash noprompt  --
```

[this is my custom.seed file](http://paste.ubuntuusers.de/410387/)

The problem is that, the installer shows the keyboard layout chooser and I have to click next. Then the correct language & keyboard layout (German) is already preselected.

What am I missing, or what's wrong in my `custom.seed` file, to automate the next click?

Answer (score 2):

I have a Swiss German keyboard and it works well with this lines in the preseed file:

```
keyboard-configuration keyboard-configuration/layout select Swiss
keyboard-configuration keyboard-configuration/unsupported_layout boolean true
keyboard-configuration keyboard-configuration/store_defaults_in_debconf_db boolean true
keyboard-configuration keyboard-configuration/variantcode string German
```